# Telethon leads to `RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'MessageMethods.send_message' was never awaited`

Tags: python, ipython, python-asyncio, telegram, telethon

I'm trying to run [this first code snippet](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/) provided by the Telethon documentation. But, after multiple problems ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60978983/4999991) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55196673/4999991)), I ended up with this modified version:

```py
import os
import sys
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient, events

# import nest_asyncio
# nest_asyncio.apply()

session_name = "<session_name>"
api_id = <api_id>
api_hash = "<api_hash>"


os.chdir(sys.path[0])

if f"{session_name}.session" in os.listdir():
    os.remove(f"{session_name}.session")

async with TelegramClient(session_name, api_id, api_hash) as client:
   client.send_message('me', 'Hello, myself!')
   print(client.download_profile_photo('me'))

   @client.on(events.NewMessage(pattern='(?i).*Hello'))
   async def handler(event):
      await event.reply('Hey!')

   client.run_until_disconnected()
```

However now I'm getting these warnings:

```
usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:23: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'MessageMethods.send_message' was never awaited
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:24: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'DownloadMethods.download_profile_photo' was never awaited
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:30: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'UpdateMethods._run_until_disconnected' was never awaited
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

when running the code on Jupyter. Now here are my questions:

- what those warning messages mean and how should I address them?
- what is the expected result of this code if working properly? Should I receive a message in Telegram or something? Because I don't recive any messages other than the signin code.
- What does the `@` symbol at the beginning of the `@client.on...` line mean? what does that line is supposed to do? From this line onwards I do not understand the code. Would appreciate if you could help me understand it.

Comment: When you run the code in Jupyter, Jupyter runs the `asyncio` event loop for you, which enables you to use `await` outside of `async def` (this is some Jupyter-specific magic).

Comment: @Lonami so how would you change the code above to work properly in both Python and Jupyter/IPython?

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add `await` the `client.send_message('me', 'Hello, myself!')` to solve that error and print after`download_profile_photo` has done its work downloads an image to `localhost` so that may be why you don't see anything. You should read [telethon documentation](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/concepts/asyncio.html) thoroughly and also [how to use photo downloads correctly](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/basic/updates.html#more-examples)

All the calls to the client have a delay and should always be awaited so that your code doesn't get blocked. You should read the [asyncio tutorial](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/concepts/asyncio.html)
The correct code would be:

```
async with TelegramClient(session_name, api_id, api_hash) as client:
   await client.send_message('me', 'Hello, myself!')
   print(await client.download_profile_photo('me'))

   @client.on(events.NewMessage(pattern='(?i).*Hello'))
   async def handler(event):
      await event.reply('Hey!')

   #await client.run_until_disconnected()
```

The @ is a decorator and you should read the [PEP related to decorators](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/), but in short words, they execute a function before yours.

In this case `@client.on(events.NewMessage` means:

When there is a new event that happens to be a message that matches the pattern specified handle it with this function called `handler`

Comment: the first three warning messages are gone except the last one `RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback`

Comment: It's because of what Lonami told you.  await client.run_until_disconnected() , i just fixed it

Comment: Thanks. I actually did try that. Although it resolves the warning message, now the interpreter goes to an infinite loop and never finishes.

Comment: Maybe if you need just to execute it once, just remove the run_until_disconnected line

Comment: OK, the infinite loop problem is now solved. But I'm not receiving any `Hello, myself!` messages anywhere. what should I expect to see? How do I know my code worked correctly?

Comment: It should send a message to your Saved Messages in Telegram. Check it, it doesn't pop out a notification.

Comment: OMG, yes it is there. Thanks a lot. I whish these explenations would be added [here](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/).

Comment: Well, it's not explicit but if you are interacting with client it means you will send a message to 'me' which means that is "your personal inbox", it's not a print, there isn't any other chat that is only for you so the logical conclusion is that it's sent there. I send messages to 'me' when i retrieve Telegram ids for example :)

Answer (score 3):

Jupyter will run the [`asyncio`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) event loop so that you can use `async for / with / await` outside of an `async def`. This conflicts with Telethon's `.sync` magic which you should try to avoid when using Jupyter, IPython, or similar.

To fix your code:

```py
from telethon import TelegramClient, events
#            ^ note no .sync

session_name = "<session_name>"
api_id = <api_id>
api_hash = "<api_hash>"

async with TelegramClient(session_name, api_id, api_hash) as client:
    await client.send_message('me', 'Hello, myself!')
    # ^ note you need to use `await` in Jupyter
    # we are avoiding the `.sync` magic so it needs to be done by yourself

    print(await client.download_profile_photo('me'))
    #     ^ same here, needs await

    @client.on(events.NewMessage(pattern='(?i).*Hello'))
    async def handler(event):
        await event.reply('Hey!')

    await client.run_until_disconnected()
    # ^ once again needs await
```

If you want code to run anywhere (Jupyter, Python shell, normal run), just be sure to do everything inside `async def`:

```py
import asyncio

from telethon import TelegramClient, events

session_name = "<session_name>"
api_id = <api_id>
api_hash = "<api_hash>"

async def main():
    async with TelegramClient(session_name, api_id, api_hash) as client:
       await client.send_message('me', 'Hello, myself!')
       print(await client.download_profile_photo('me'))

       @client.on(events.NewMessage(pattern='(?i).*Hello'))
       async def handler(event):
           await event.reply('Hey!')

       await client.run_until_disconnected()

# Only this line changes, the rest will work anywhere.
# Jupyter
await main()

# Otherwise
asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: I will check this. but is there a way to have a code which works both in Python shell and Jupyter/IPython similarly?

Comment: I have updated my answer to reflect your new concerns.

Comment: I ran the second code block and got `RuntimeError: asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop`

Comment: Then I'm afraid the code in Jupyter has to be slightly different, and use `await main()` instead.

Comment: I actually did try that but I get [lots of warning messages](https://pastebin.com/umXmBpjj) and the compiler never finishes!

Comment: removing the line `await client.run_until_disconnected()` solved the problem.