# How to use crontab to send photos by telegram bot using python?

Tags: python, cron, telegram

I have an issue that when crontab run my python script, my telegram bot cannot read local .png files. Does anyone how to deal with this problem?

```
import telegram
chat_id = '***'
BOT_TOKEN = '***'
bot = telegram.Bot(token=BOT_TOKEN)

bot.sendPhoto(photo=open(os.path.abspath('./github/project/photo.png'), 'rb'), chat_id=chat_id)
```

My crontab task:

```
* * * * 1-5 ~/.pyenv/versions/miniconda3-4.3.30/envs/project1/bin/python ~/github/project/test.py > ~/log/output.log 2>&1
```

I have tried saving photo in memory first but it doesn't work.

Comment: The title is misleading - looks like the problem is in your script and not in your cronjob?

Comment: Actually, if I run this " ~/.pyenv/versions/miniconda3-4.3.30/envs/project1/bin/python ~/github/project/test.py" in terminal, it works. However, it doesn't work using crontab to run my python script.

Comment: As usual with cron, the question is how you installed it into the crontab or what user this is getting executed as. This also decides about file permissions and the location of `~`.

Comment: Also an issue I have faced sometimes: you may need a new line the one you just added to the crontab, otherwise it won't run.

Answer (score 0):

Raul is correct.  Cron is not the culprit.  Check your python.

os.path.abspath() is going to find the absolute path of the file for you.

So, the name of the file is the only argument needed, no relative path.

`bot.sendPhoto(photo=open(os.path.abspath('photo.png'), 'rb'), chat_id=chat_id)`

https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html

Comment: I see. I have revised, but there is another problem. The error message is "RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Bot.send_photo' was never awaited
  bot.sendPhoto(photo=open(os.path.abspath('photo.png'), 'rb'), chat_id=chat_id)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback"

Comment: No, it searches for a relative path, but it is resolved relative to the current working directory, which is your home directory when you run the script from `cron`.

Comment: I solved RuntimeWarning by this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75076069/runtimewarning-enable-tracemalloc-to-get-the-object-allocation-traceback-not

Comment: Great! It looked like the person implemented async and it worked out, which makes sense since this type of thing takes a while to finish.